# Using vicino or vicina

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Can someone explain if there is a difference in meaning or usage between vicino and vicina. As far as I can tell, they seem to be interchangeable, yet I've seen both used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your confusion comes from the fact that *vicino* can be a noun, an adjective, or an adverb; *vicina* can only be a noun or an adjective, and it is the feminine version of that usage of *vicino*. In this sense, you also have the plural version.

Used as a noun, *vicino* means "neighbor" and *vicina* would be the feminine version of it:

> Il mio vicino mi ha regalato una torta, la mia vicina invece è veramente antipatica;

used as an adjective, it means "close, neighboring":

> La mia borsa è vicina alla tua, quei paesi vicini sono molto belli,

used as an adverb, *vicino* means "near":

> La ragazza sta arrivando vicino al treno

Comment: "La ragazza sta arrivando vicino al treno"... this sentence sounds really odd... probably because anyone would say *La ragazza si sta avvicinando al treno* instead of using *arrivare* + *vicino*.

Comment: @Bakuriu You're right, but I couldn't think of a better example!

Comment: "La ragazza sta andando vicino al treno" oppure "la ragazza si sta spostando vicino al treno".

Comment: La ragazza è vicino al treno (è = si trova, "vicino" is used as an adverb)

Comment: La ragazza è vicina al treno ("è" forms a predicate adjective, and "vicina" is obviously used as an adjective)