# Essere vicino o vicina?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, adjectives, adverbs

Tenendo conto del fatto che sono una donna, quale tra queste due frasi sarebbe la scelta giusta?

> - Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di essergli *vicino*.
> - Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di essergli *vicina*.

Ho letto [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1994/707), ma non è chiaro a me se in questo contesto se si debba usare l'aggettivo o l'avverbio.

---

## Aggiornamento:

Leggendo i commenti al Canto XXIX dell'*Inferno* di Dante Alighieri da due fonti diverse, ho trovato degli esempi interessanti sull'uso di "vicino" e "vicina" per esprimere la stessa idea:

> - È qui riassunta la mitica pestilenza di Egina, isola **vicino** ad Atene, [...]. (Bianca Garavelli, BUR).
> - *Egina*: isoletta **vicina** ad Atene, che [...]. (Anna Maria Chiavacci Leonardi, Einaudi).

Comment: Un piccolo *remark* su una cosa che la maggior parte degli Italiani che conosco sbaglia: se sei vicina a più persone, non *gli* sei vicina, sei vicina *loro*.

Comment: @writingthesis: Perché "essergli vicina" non è corretto e si deve dire "esser loro vicina"?

Comment: Perché è un [pronome personale complemento](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronome_personale_in_italiano#Pronomi_personali_complemento). 
"Sono vicina al mio alunno" = Gli sono vicina.
"Sono vicina alla mia alunna" = Le sono vicina.
"Sono vicina ai miei alunni" = Sono vicina loro/ sono loro vicina.

Usare "gli" invece di "loro" si sente sempre di più ma è ufficialmente scorretto. Come dicevo, comunque, la maggior parte degli Italiani che conosco (me incluso) lo sbaglia.

Comment: @writingthesis: I miei libri di grammatica ammettono *gli* come forma atona della terza persona plurale del pronome personale complemento di termine.

Comment: Nel libro *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo (edizioni ELI) appare questo esempio: "Ho parlato con Cristina e Mario, gli ho chiesto se stasera vogliono venire a cena da noi." // "Ho parlato con Cristina e Mario, ho chiesto loro se stasera vogliono venire a cena da noi."

Answer (score 4):

Io direi, nel tuo caso, *vicina*.

I commenti sembrano dare una buona spiegazione:

Quando si ha *essere* + *vicino* ,  hai un *predicato nominale*, quindi coniughi l'aggettivo

> Sono sempre vicina ai miei alunni nel momento del bisogno.

Altrimenti, ad esempio quando hai un verbo di movimento, usi *vicino* come avverbio, da solo o per formare una [locuzione preposizionale](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/locuzioni-preposizionali_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/):

> Se vai troppo vicino alla porta scatta l'allarme

Answer (score 2):

Il dubbio che si espone nella domanda è quello della scelta tra

> essere *vicina* (aggettivo) agli alunni

oppure

> essere *vicino* (avverbio) agli alunni,

frase in cui si sta infatti usando la locuzione preposizionale "vicino a".

Questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/vicino-roma--vicino-a-roma/55) dà la seguente spiegazione al riguardo (grassetto mio):

> «L'alternativa è tra aggettivo, quindi concordato col sostantivo a cui si riferisce, e tra locuzione preposizionale (*vicino a*, *lontano da*), invariabile in numero, genere e grado: è dunque errato dire «più vicino a quelle occidentali», con un comparativo possibile solo con aggettivi e avverbi. Di là da questo caso specifico, l'italiano offre da sempre possibilità di scelta, **con una certa preferenza (non con l'obbligo) per l'aggettivo in presenza della copula**: «abito in una città *vicino a* Roma» / *vicina a* Roma»; «Tivoli è una città *vicina* (ma anche *vicino*) *a* Roma». Per documentare l'antichità dell'alternativa, basteranno alcuni esempi dei secoli XIII-XVI, attinti dal serbatoio della *LIZ* (*Letteratura italiana Zanichelli*, a cura di P. Stoppelli e E. Picchi, Bologna 2001). Con l'aggettivo: «Pisa è *vicina a* Firenze a miglia XL» (Compagni), «altre frontiere *vicine a* quel luogo» (Villani), «la placata dea, ch'era *lontana / da* lor benivolenza» (Alberto della Piagentina), «imperò che [questi uomini] non sono molto *lontani da* terra» (Manerbi). Con la locuzione preposizionale: «nelle città *vicino a* loro vista» (Villani), «in una sua villa quattro miglia *vicino a* Roma» (Boccaccio), «da una parte della sala assai *lontano da* ogni uomo con la donna si pose a sedere» (Boccaccio), «ad Aversa, dieci miglia *lontano da* Napoli» (Vasari).

Quindi, nella frase della domanda, tutte e due  le alternative sono corrette. Tuttavia, la presenza del verbo copulativo "essere" fa che ci sia una certa preferenza per l'aggettivo "vicina":

> Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di essergli vicina.

Comment: Al mio orecchio, “essere vicino agli alunni” indica presenza fisica, mentre “essere vicina agli alunni” può indicare vicinanza astratta.

Comment: Interessante, @egreg: può darsi che sia così.

Answer (score -3):

Teoricamente, poiché il complemento oggetto sarebbe "alunni" dovrebbe essere "Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di esser loro vicini."

Tutto questo, ovviamente, se hai intenzione di usare "vicino" riferito agli alunni.

Comment: @Charo che* cerco*

Comment: @writingthesis: Grazie! Adesso correggo il mio commento.

Comment: Sono io che cerco di essere vicina o vicino agli alunni.

Comment: Vorrei far notare che "Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di esser loro vicini" è una frase priva di senso

Comment: Io userei "Cerco di avere molta pazienza con i miei alunni e di esser loro vicino/a" a seconda del mio sesso.