# Sull'uso di "gli" come terza persona plurale del pronome personale complemento di termine

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns

In un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5240/707) si è menzionato che usare "gli" invece di "loro" per la terza persona plurale del pronome personale complemento di termine  "si sente sempre di più ma è ufficialmente scorretto". Si è detto anche che molti italiani sbagliano su questo aspetto, cioè usano "gli" invece di "loro".

Comunque, i miei libri di grammatica per studenti stranieri ammettono *gli* come forma atona della terza persona plurale del pronome personale complemento di termine. In *Grammatica e pratica della lingua italiana per studenti stranieri* di Federica Colombo (edizioni ELI) appaiono questi esempi:

> - "Ho parlato con Cristina e Mario, *gli* ho chiesto se stasera vogliono venire a cena da noi."
> - "Ho parlato con Cristina e Mario, ho chiesto *loro* se stasera vogliono venire a cena da noi."

Questo libro afferma che la forma col pronome *gli* è più comune oggi, soprattutto nel parlato.

Immagino dunque che non si tratti di "forma corretta" versus "forma sbagliata", ma di forma più formale o meno. È così? E se è così,  fino a che punto questo uso del pronome "gli" è da considerarsi informale?

Comment: Sono contento di aver scatenato la discussione :)

Comment: È più comune sentire `gli ho chiesto` piuttosto che `ho chiesto loro`, anche in un contesto formale. Credo che in questo caso la regola sia stata sopraffatta dall'evoluzione naturale della lingua parlata. `Ho chiesto loro`, nonostante sia la forma "ufficiale", suona come un costrutto antico, in quanto non se ne fa più uso nella lingua parlata.

Comment: Non è affatto sbagliato *gli ho chiesto* invece di *ho chiesto loro*; è una forma perfettamente accettabile, anche se certi pedanti grammatici storcono il naso (appoggiati dalle grammatiche per la scuola elementare).

Comment: @egreg Posso usare "pedante grammatico" nella mia descrizione su SE?

Comment: @writingthesis Senz'altro. `;-)`

Comment: Ho appena letto "Io Partenope" e sono rimasto "turbato" dall'uso frequentissimo che fa del pronome "gli" riferito a più persone, ma persino, e molto spesso, anche a singole donne.
Leggo che il libro ha vinto il premio Campiello e che l'autore è stato proposto per il Nobel... Ma allora, a scuola mi hanno proprio insegnato male? Giuseppe

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @giuseppe! Il tuo post è stato convertito in un commento perché lo spazio dove l'avevi scritto è riservato per le risposte alla domanda fatta dall'OP. Sull'uso del pronome "gli" riferito a parecchie persone ci sono già queste due risposte basate su articoli della Treccani e la Crusca. Ma sull'uso che hai osservato riferito a una singola donna, sarebbe interessante porre una domanda. Potresti farlo usando "Ask Question"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oltre al già citato Treccani, anche [**la Crusca**](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/en/italian-language/language-consulting/questions-answers/uso-per) lo riconosce:

> Per riassumere, l'uso di gli in luogo di loro, a loro, a essi e a esse
>   è da considerare senz'altro corretto (Ora vado dai tuoi amici e gli
>   dico che la devono smettere di fare chiasso), tranne che, forse, nel
>   caso di registri altamente formali (Il parroco espresse loro le sue
>   più sentite condoglianze).

A me personalmente non piace, ma questa è un'altra storia.

Comment: +1 per "a me personalmente non piace"

Answer (score 3):

**[Gli](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/pronomi-personali_%28La-grammatica-italiana%29/)**: (Treccanionline)

> - L’uso della forma pronominale atona gli in funzione di complemento di ➔termine in riferimento non solo al maschile singolare, ma anche al maschile plurale **è ormai da considerarsi accettabile in quasi tutti i livelli di lingua.
>     Nel parlato colloquiale, quest’uso è molto comune.**
>
>   - Ho incontrato i suoi genitori e gli ho chiesto di salutarmelo
>   - Senti Mario e Paola: domandagli se ci raggiungono per l’aperitivo
> - Ma si trova ampiamente attestato anche in tutta la tradizione letteraria:
>
>   - Chi si cura di costoro a Milano? Chi gli darebbe retta? (A. Manzoni, I promessi sposi)
> - **A favorire l’uso di gli al plurale c’è anche il fatto che il pronome loro è bisillabico** (e dunque tonico, a differenza di tutti gli altri pronomi personali di questo tipo) e dev’essere sempre posto dopo il verbo
>     i suoi familiari non seppero nulla per quattro anni. Non venne mai detto loro se era stato accusato di qualche reato, processato o imprigionato («Corriere della Sera»).

Answer (score 2):

Usare *gli* al plurale non è mai stato sbagliato:

> Ma poi che con loro in piacevoli ragionamenti entrata fu, essendosi alquanto partito messer Torello, essa piacevolmente donde fossero e dove andassero **gli** domandò …

—Giovanni Boccaccio, c. 1353, [*Il Decameron*, terza giornata, nona novella](http://tinyurl.com/y947vbpo)

> … io credo che il più presentaneo rimedio sia il battere alli Padri Gesuiti, come quelli che sanno assai sopra le comuni lettere de’ frati: però **gli** potrà dar la copia della lettera, ed anco legger**gli**, se le piacerà, questa che scrivo a lei …

—Galileo Galilei, 1615, [lettera a Piero Dini](https://tinyurl.com/y8dzy8nw)

> La legge l’hanno fatta loro, come **gli** è piaciuto …

—Alessandro Manzoni, 1827, [*I promessi sposi*, capitolo VI](https://tinyurl.com/yalamgk4)

> Chi si cura di costoro a Milano? Chi **gli** darebbe retta?

—Alessandro Manzoni, 1827, [*I promessi sposi*, capitolo XI](https://tinyurl.com/y8gfzfjc)

> Così il trambusto andava sempre crescendo a quel primo disgraziato forno; perché tutti coloro che **gli** pizzicavan le mani di fare qualche bell’impresa, correvan là, dove gli amici erano i più forti, e l’impunità sicura.

—Alessandro Manzoni, 1827, [*I promessi sposi*, capitolo XII](https://tinyurl.com/y7rgwl7p)

> Lì non era altro che una, lasciatemi dire, accozzaglia di gente varia d’età e di sesso, che stava a vedere. All’intimazioni che **gli** venivan fatte, di sbandarsi e di dar luogo, rispondevano con un lungo e cupo mormorio; nessuno si muoveva.

—Alessandro Manzoni, 1827, [*I promessi sposi*, capitolo XIII](https://tinyurl.com/y7tlcvhz)

Infatti, *gli* singolare e *gli* plurale hanno [etimologie diverse](http://forum.accademiadellacrusca.it/forum_8/interventi/3557.shtml.html):

> Dal punto di vista etimologico, il 'gli' in questione deriva da due distinti dativi pronominali latini: 'illi' (singolare, comune a tutti i generi: 'a lui', 'a lei'), e 'illis' (plurale, anch’esso comune a tutti i generi: 'ad essi', 'ad esse'), ossia, pur coincidendo come forma, il 'gli' pronome singolare e quello plurale hanno origine diversa tra loro …