# Understanding "addosso" at the end of a sentence

Tags: grammar, adverbs, sentences

Dictionaries translate *addosso* to *on*, a preposition.

I saw some example sentences and I'm having trouble understanding some of them. For example, I don't understand this sentence:

> **ci** viene **addosso** (it comes on us)
>   **gli** è caduto il ramo **addosso** (the branch fell on top of him)

IMO, it would look more intuitive if written as this:

> viene **addosso a noi**
>   il ramo è caduto **addosso a lui**

Can anyone explain the first sentence, with *addosso* at the end and not followed by *a*?

Comment: In your examples, "gli" takes the role of "a lui" and "ci" takes the role of "a noi" - in Italian they're called _indirect pronouns_ see for example http://www.locuta.com/pronind.html

Answer (score 4):

The sentences

> ci viene addosso
>
> viene addosso a noi

are “grammatically equivalent”, but not strictly “semantically equivalent”. The pronoun *ci* has the same role as *a noi*, but it's a question of emphasis. Similarly for *gli* which stands for *a lui*, *a lei* or *a loro*.<sup>1</sup>

With *gli è caduto il ramo addosso* the emphasis is on the person who’s hit by the branch, rather than on the branch; to the contrary, *il ramo gli è caduto addosso* would put more emphasis on the branch. A third form is possible: *il ramo è caduto addosso a lui* would convey the idea that the branch fell onto him and not other people.

Similarly, *viene addosso a noi* could imply that it came against us and not other people.

Nuances, but they're important. I'd say that *ci viene addosso* would be the preferred form unless a particular shift on emphasis is needed.

---

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup> Prescriptive grammars may say that *gli* for *a loro* is an error; they're contradicted by *many* authoritative writers and speakers.

Comment: Are there still actually recent grammars that say that plural _gli_ is an error?

Comment: @DaG I hope not.

Comment: So the "*addosso* at end" structure is just *a noi* turned into *ci* and then moved to before the verb, as well as the emphasis change, right?

Comment: @iBug Basically so; *addosso* is an adverb that modifies the verb. The position of the pronoun can change: a not so easy feature of Italian, because also the form changes (mi=a me, ti=a te, gli=a lui/lei/loro, ci=a noi, vi=a voi).

Comment: @iBug: Let me stress that the emphasis is very important. You'd use “viene addosso a noi” almost only in a situation like “Ah, viene addosso a Gigi?” “No, viene addosso _a noi_!”. Used in an unmarked way, “viene addosso a noi” could sound even somewhat unnatural.

Comment: @DaG: It has been discussed here: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5255/sulluso-di-gli-come-terza-persona-plurale-del-pronome-personale-complemento-d.