# "Gli diede tutto il suo denaro." Why does this start with the article 'gli'?

Tags: pronouns, articles

This translates to "She gave him all of her money." According to my Anki deck. Is the 'gli' somehow referring to 'him'?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! In this sentence, "gli" is not an article: it's an indirect object pronoun.

Comment: Thanks Charo that allowed me to search for an explanation :)! If you place your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in the [VIVIT website](https://www.viv-it.org/schede/pronomi-personali), from Accademia della Crusca, the word "gli" in Italian is not only an article: it's also an indirect object personal pronoun.

This is the case in your sentence: "gli" is an indirect object personal pronoun, which can be masculine singular and then translated as "to him", as you can see in this [table](https://www.viv-it.org/sites/default/files/u80/pronomi-pers-sing_1.JPG),
or plural (see [the answers to this question](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5255) for more details) and translated as "to them", as stated in this [other table](https://www.viv-it.org/sites/default/files/u80/pronomi-pers-plur_1.JPG).