# Uso di "costringere" + aggettivo

Tags: word-usage, verbs, adjectives

Leggendo questa [notizia su Euronews](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://it.euronews.com/2020/04/28/nel-2019-il-clima-ha-provocato-il-triplo-degli-sfollamenti-rispetto-alle-guerre&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjcj4nQ24rpAhW4BGMBHdJfBtEQFjAGegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw2NzysUVe_mOxWWJ7n5f09C), ho trovato questa frase (grassetto mio):

> Oltre 2.8 milioni di persone **sono costrette lontani** dalle proprie terre, soprattutto a causa di conflitti come quello ucraino.

La costruzione con il verbo "costringere" seguito da un aggettivo ha attirato la mia attenzione perché non l'avevo mai incontrata prima; e anche perché nelle mie lingue non esiste un costrutto analogo a questo.

Potresti spiegarmi come si utilizza, se veramente si usa in italiano, facendo qualche esempio?

Immagino che (inoltre al fatto che si dovrebbe scrivere 2,8 e non 2.8) in questa frase sia una svista perché dovrebbe essere "sono costrette lontane" oppure "sono costretti lontani" (e come si dovrebbe fare questa concordanza forse sarebbe oggetto di un'altra domanda).

**Aggiornamento:**

Siccome la frase dell'articolo di Euronews è stata subito qualificata come sospetta di "italiano cattivo", riporto un altro esempio (che potrebbe anche trattarsi di "italiano cattivo": non ho idea su questo e perciò pongo questa domanda) di questa struttura che ho trovato su [questo sito web](http://www.forlitoday.it/cronaca/resto-a-casa-e-cucino-civitella-lancia-un-gustoso-contest-social.html) (ho simplificato la frase e anche qui il grassetto è mio). Ricercando su Internet, se ne possono trovare altri:

> L'emergenza ci **ha costretti chiusi** tra le mura domestiche.

Comment: Mi pare una forzatura, essere costretto penso vada seguito da "a", perché si è costretti a fare qualcosa. Se lo si usa come aggettivo legato allo spazio lo userei seguito da "in", (essere costretti in casa, nel senso di confinati). Costretto come aggettivo non penso preveda altri avverbi o altre particelle.  È una mia opinione da madrelingua, per questo metto in commento e non come risposta, non ho elementi dimostrativi. Se dovessi scegliere, la frase in quetione l'avrei fatta così: 2.8 milioni di persone sono costrette (a stare) "lontano" dalle proprie terre. Fra parentesi il sottinteso.

Comment: Solo un'osservazione sulla concordanza: il soggetto, a rigore, è “2.8 milioni” quindi il maschile non sarebbe un problema, anche se in genere la concordanza ad sensum è ammessa.

Comment: Comunque non mi sembra che questa frase sia contraddistinta da pignoleria formale: “costringere” + aggettivo suona sicuramente strano, e “due e otto decimi” in italiano si scrive “2,8”.

Comment: @DaG:  Nel mio paese c'è persino un decreto pubblicato sul BOE che stabilisce che si deve usare la virgola e non il punto per separare la parte decimale dalla parte entera, ma devo ammettere che anch'io a volte uso il punto.

Comment: Dovrebbe esserci un avverbio: *sono costrette lontano*.

Comment: @egreg: Tuttavia, cercando su Internet, trovo cose come, ad esempio, [questa](http://www.forlitoday.it/cronaca/resto-a-casa-e-cucino-civitella-lancia-un-gustoso-contest-social.html): «"Siccome non vogliamo rinunciare alle tradizioni e considerato che l'emergenza ci ha costretti chiusi tra le mura domestiche, vi esortiamo ugualmente a dilettarvi con le vostre creazioni culinarie", è l'invito del sindaco Claudio Milandri.» Non so se questo significhi che ci sia certa confusione sull'argomento.

Comment: Probabilmente mi ripeto: il buon Italiano è raro, specialmente in TV. Le otto parole all'inizio della frase sono una perla di *italiacano*. E sono d'accordo a riguardo del punto decimale, si dovrebbe scrivere e leggere "due virgola otto milioni".

Comment: La preposizione è diversa: "viaggiamo lontano da casa”, “restiamo chiusi in casa”; *siamo costretti lontano da casa*, *siamo costretti chiusi in casa*. Quanto ai milioni, sarebbe bastato dire “quasi tre milioni”.

Comment: Sì, @egreg, ma "siamo costretti chiusi in casa" non è un esempio di "costringere" + aggettivo?

Comment: @DaG: Se il soggetto è maschile, non dovrebbe essere "sono costretti" invece di "sono costrette"? Veramente non sono sicura se si debba dire "due milioni di persone sono costrette" oppure "due milioni di persone sono costretti".

Comment: @Charo Certo, si può usare “costringere+aggettivo”, ma non con “lontano da casa”. In ogni caso, l'aggettivo va concordato e se si usa la concordanza *ad sensum* si concorda con “costrette”, quindi “lontane”. Certamente non “lontani”.

Comment: @egreg:  E, se non si usa la concordanza *ad sensum* , si dovrebbe dire, per esempio, "due milioni di persone sono costretti chiusi in casa"?

Comment: @egreg: E, il problema della scelta tra aggettivo o avverbio, non sarebbe lo stesso di quello che si espone in questa [domanda](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5240/)? Per esempio, si può dire sia "isola vicino ad Atene", sia "isola vicina ad Atene". Credo di cominciare a non capire più nulla!

Comment: @Charo: Giusto, scusa la svista: se vogliamo concordare con “milioni”, dovrebbe essere “Due milioni... sono costretti...” (ma l'aggettivo che segue mi fa aggricciare, indipendentemente dal maschile o dal femminile). Io direi “costretti a andare/finire lontani...” o nel caso della seconda frase “...ci ha costretti a stare/rimanere chiusi...”.

Comment: @DaG: Forse la questione della concordanza in una frase il cui soggetto è "due milioni di persone" sarebbe oggetto di un'altra domanda, non so. Nelle mie lingue, la concordanza in una frase con questo soggetto (tradotto, ovviamente) si fa sempre (credo, in questo momento mi pare di dubitare di tutto) con "persone" e non con "milioni", ma non abbiamo verbi coniugati con l'ausiliare "essere". Cioè, mi riferisco a frasi con un predicato nominale.

Comment: @egreg: Se ho capito bene questo [articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca](https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/vicino-roma--vicino-a-roma/55), si può usare sia l'aggettivo (*lontani da/lontane da*), sia l'avverbio (*lontano da*).