# Vicino vs vicina

Tags: grammar, adjectives, gender

Vicino vs vicina:

> Il supermercato è vicino al ponte.

Sounds right, as both "supermercato" and "ponte" are masculine.

> La libreria è vicina al parco.

Doesn't make sense to me because "parco" is masculine.  Is it because "libreria" is feminine?  Does it take the gender of the subject?

Comment: I notice now that a very similar topic has been covered at least two times, [here](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1991/using-vicino-or-vicina) and [here](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5240/essere-vicino-o-vicina).

Comment: Yes, I saw the first one, but it didn't help much.  It only asked the difference between vicino and vicina, not how they were used.  That's why I included the two examples.  As for the second example, it's in Italian, and I'm just starting to learn Italian, so it was not helpful for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the adjective governed by the verb *essere* (to be) takes the gender of the subject, and in your sentence *libreria* is indeed the subject. Think “*la libreria è bella*”, and compare with “*la libreria è vicina (al parco)*”.

Comment: I'm not really convinced. What about *la libreria è situata vicino al parco*? Do you see any difference in the grammatical role of *vicino*?

Comment: Of course, @egreg, that is a different use of *vicino*, as an adverb rather than as an adjective, and as such it is invariant; I might even write, say, *la libreria sta vicino al parco*, but *la libreria è vicinX al parco* sounds more like a description of the bookshop, and as such I'd use an adjective.

Comment: It seems to me more like the description of the bookshop's *location*.

Comment: Yes, @greg, and by the same token we might say that *la libreria è rossa* is a description of the bookshop's colour, but I cannot see how this affect the agreement between noun and adjective. Do you actually find it more idiomatic to say *la libreria è vicino al parco*? (Not a rethorical question.)

Comment: *la libreria è vicino al parco* refers to the park; *la libreria è ampia* refers to the bookshop. I'm not saying the first is better or worse than using *vicina*, I'm only saying it's not “black and white”.

Comment: *La libreria è vicino al parco* sounds very unusual to me, but it may well be a regional/personal thing.